# How binding works in Angular 2 as compared to Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, data-binding

In Angular 1.x we use to have digest cycle which triggers the watchers and update the view whenever there is a change in the binded property.
In Angular 2 we see that there is interpolation(one way binding) of properties in view when there is a change so how does this one way binding works under the hood.

Can someone please explain this?

Thanks

I found few pointers which suggested that there is something called [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) which helped getting away with digest cycle and $apply in angular 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Angular 1**

- When you write an expression ({{aModel}}), behind the scenes Angular sets up a watcher on the scope model, which in turn updates the view whenever the model changes

  ```
  $scope.$watch('aModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //update the DOM with newValue
   });
  ```
- The second argument passed to $watch() is known as a listener function, and is called whenever the value of aModel changes. It is easy for us to grasp that when the value of aModel changes this listener is called, updating the expression in HTML.
- $digest cycle is responsible for firing the watchers.The $digest cycle starts as a result of a call to $scope.$digest().
- Angular doesn’t directly call $digest(). Instead, it calls $scope.$apply(), which in turn calls $rootScope.$digest(). As a result of this, a digest cycle starts at the $rootScope, and subsequently visits all the child scopes calling the watchers along the way.

for more detail plz visit : [Angular Digist cycle](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

**Angular 2**

- Basically application state change can be caused by three things

  1.**Events** - click, submit, …

  2.**XHR** - Fetching data from a remote server

  3.**Timers** - setTimeout(), setInterval()

They are all asynchronous. Which brings us to the conclusion that, basically whenever some asynchronous operation has been performed, our application state might have changed. This is when someone needs to tell Angular to update the view.

- Angular allows us to use native APIs directly. There are no interceptor methods we have to call so Angular gets notified to update the DOM.
- Zones take care of all these things. In fact, Angular comes with its own zone called **NgZone**
- The short version is, that somewhere in Angular’s source code, there’s this thing called ApplicationRef, which listens to NgZones **onTurnDone** event. Whenever this event is fired, it executes a tick() function which essentially performs change detection.

[image]

for more please visit : [Angular 2 change detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, AngularJS was all about Two-way databinding, that ended up being very costly in terms of ressource usage with the $scope and the $watchers. You could always do One-way databinding, but that was not well made for that and it became hard to work with AngularJS.

With Angular2, since it's a different Framework, you can do both pretty easily.

Here is a good link that explains the different databindings possibilities :

- http://tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-data-bindings-one-way-two-way-with-examples

There are even more differences between those two Frameworks that you should learn about.

Here are some cool links that I discovered a few months ago that are quite helpful to understand why they went from AngularJS to Angular2 and contain all the answers you are looking for :

- http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/04/06/angular2-first-impressions/
- http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2015/09/angular-2-survey-results.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2

Zone.js is something else :

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/

Have fun reading !

Comment: It turns out Zone.js is responsible for bindings (change detection) in Angular 2. There is a nice article which provides insight. Angular has extented Zone.js to create ngZone which listens for event and run change detection on each component. Link to the article [https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html]